# Apache RewriteRule not splitting variables into query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
<Directory /var/www/html/api/>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(.*)$ index.php?version=$1&method=$2&param1=$3&param2=$4&param3=$5
</Directory>
```

The following URL: http://myserver.com/api/v1/hello/there/stranger

```
array(5) { ["version"]=> string(2) "v1" ["method"]=> string(21) "/hello/there/stranger" ["param1"]=> string(0) "" ["param2"]=> string(0) "" ["param3"]=> string(0) "" }
```

The version string splits correctly, but the method string seems to take the rest of the contents and put it into one string, instead of splitting it into param1, param2 and param3 which was my goal.

How can I 'rewrite' the RewriteRule so that it correctly splits these variables into their matching query string?

Answer (score 1):

It is not splitting because your regex is not breaking it into multiple groups.

Your regex is capturing `(.*)` after `v1/` which will just capture `/hello/there/stranger` in a single group.

You can use these different rules:

```
# 2 parts
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/[^/]+)/?$ index.php?version=$1&method=$2 [L,QSA]

# 3 parts
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/[^/]+)(/[^/]+)/?$ index.php?version=$1&method=$2&param1=$3 [L,QSA]

# 4 parts
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/[^/]+)(/[^/]+)(/[^/]+)/?$ index.php?version=$1&method=$2&param1=$3&param2=$4 [L,QSA]

# 5 parts
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/[^/]+)(/[^/]+)(/[^/]+)(/[^/]+)/?$ index.php?version=$1&method=$2&param1=$3&param2=$4&param3=$54 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This seems to have broken the original RewriteRule that routes the request to index.php. Any ideas why?

Comment: The problem seems to occur when there are not enough arguments provided in the URL. Please could you alter your answer so that you don't have to supply all the parameters in order for the index.php route to work?

Comment: It can be done but I will need example URLs for all the cases when all arguments are NOT there.